# System hangs on using mclapply

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am running this code from Linux Terminal on a Ubuntu 14.04 PC with core i7 Processor and 4 GB RAM:

```
library(parallel)
workerFunc <- function(n) { return(n^2) }
a <- function(){
  CurrentTime <- Sys.time()
  res <- lapply(values, workerFunc)
  TimeTaken <- Sys.time() - CurrentTime
  print(TimeTaken)
}
b <- function(){
  CurrentTime <- Sys.time()
  numWorkers <- detectCores()
  res <- mclapply(values, workerFunc, mc.cores = numWorkers-2)
  TimeTaken <- Sys.time() - CurrentTime
  print(TimeTaken)
}
c <- function(n){
  values <<- 1:n
  print("Evaluating a : ")
  a()
  print("Evaluating b : ")
  b()
}
```

Running `c()` with n=9999999 as argument, the code runs for `a()` but on reaching `b()`, the system hangs. For smaller values of n as n=9999, n=999, both `a()` and `b()` works fine. What can be the possible solution?

Comment: Using your functions and n=9999999, the RAM use increased of about 4 Gb for few seconds. This is more or less the maximum of RAM you have on your machine. Probably the reason of your problem.

Comment: My system has 4GB memory. On running `htop` on linux terminal,  for `c(9999999)`, `a()` runnnng on single cpu core showed stats for 100% cpu utilization. On reaching `b()`, the entire system hanged (no response and the cpu utilization froze at 100%, RAM utilization never crossed 1.5 GB)

Comment: On my machine (Ubuntu 14.10, 32 Gb), there is a short peak with + 4 Gb used for few seconds.

Comment: What happens if you set `mc.preschedule = FALSE`?

Comment: with res <- mclapply(values, workerFunc, mc.cores = numWorkers-2,mc.preschedule = FALSE) in b(), the results are : > c(99999) [1] "Evaluating a : " Time difference of 0.09889889 secs "Evaluating b : "Time difference of 3.609951 mins